# Determine the number of ordered pairs of integers $(a, b)$ for which $ab \geqslant 0$ and $a^3+b^3+99ab=33^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Determine the number of ordered pairs of integers $(a, b)$ for which $ab \geqslant 0$ and $$a^3+b^3+99ab=33^3$$

I managed to get somewhere with the problem. Firstly noting that $$(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$$

from here on if $a+b=33$ we have $$33^3 = a^3+b^3+99ab$$

however here I got stuck, I got a tip that $a+b-33$ would be a factor of some expression here, but I don't see this?

Comment: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/factorise-a-3-b-3-c-3-3abc/

Comment: you can use [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) to divide your term by a+b-33

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following lab bhattacharjee's hint one obtains
$$a^3+b^3+99ab-33^3=(a+b-33)(a^2-ab+b^2+33a+33b+1089)\ .$$
This shows that all pairs $(a,b)$ with $a+b=33$ solve the given equation. To find out wether there are more solutions we look at the polynomial
$$\eqalign{p(a,b)&:=a^2-ab+b^2+33a+33b+1089\cr &=(a+33)^2-(a+33)(b+33)+(b+33)^2\cr &=u^2-uv+v^2\ ,\cr}$$
with $u:=a+33$, $v:=b+33$.  Since the quadratic form $q(u,v):=u^2-uv+v^2$ is positive definite we have $p(a,b)>0$ when $a\geq0$, $b\geq0$. It follows that
$$a^3+b^3+99ab=33^3\tag{1}$$
can only hold when $a+b=33$. We therefore obtain $34$ nonnegative integer solutions $(a,b)$, resp., the $17$ unordered pairs
$$\{k,33-k\}\qquad(0\leq k\leq 16)\ .$$